# Error while creating a 'Near' application

Tags: blockchain, javascript, dapp-development

I'm trying to create a 'Near' bootstrap application using this command `npx create-near-app blockvote --contract js --frontend react --tests js`.

This isn't creating bootstrap files as it should.
The only message I'm getting is

```
 ======================================================
 Welcome to NEAR! Learn more: https://docs.near.org/
 Let's get your dApp ready.
======================================================
(NEAR collects anonymous information on the commands used. No personal information that could identify you is shared)

Notice: On Win32 please use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install
Exiting now.
```

I require this for my final year project.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, you need to install Linux on Windows with WSL first. If you are using Mac, the command `npx create-near-app blockvote --contract js --frontend react --tests js` will create the bootstrap application.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Comment: I get this error message on WSL - Ubuntu. create-near-app still thinks I am on windows. Anyone?